# Why Trigger on `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` doesn't work when the value is false?

Tags: wpf, triggers, eventtrigger

I want to change the InputLanguage on `Textbox.GotFocus` and `Textbox.LostFocus`,so i do this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="EnglishTextStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="InputLanguageManager.InputLanguage" Value="en-us" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="InputLanguageManager.InputLanguage" Value="fa-ir" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

it chages the InputLanguage to `en-us` but doesn't return it back to `fa-ir`,what's the problem?

Comment: This code works. Try changing Property="Text" instead InputLanguageManager.InputLanguage and you must ensure to focused other control. Also you can evalute "IsFocused".

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the Type too:

```
<Trigger Property="TextBox.IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False">
     <Setter Property="TextBox.InputLanguageManager.InputLanguage" Value="fa-ir" />
</Trigger>
```